# Provide internet access to VM in private network through another VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I have use vagrant to defined 2 VMS (FW and server).

- FW has 2 nics: 1 public network with an IP from my LAN and 1 private network
- server has 1 nic: private network.

I am trying to provide internet access to the server from the FW but it doesn't get it and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is the Vagrant file:

```
 # -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
  config.vm.define "fw" do |fw|
    fw.vm.hostname = "FW"
    fw.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "wlp0s20f3", ip: "192.168.1.254", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    fw.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.254", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    fw.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "ip route del default"
    fw.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "ip route add default via 192.168.1.1"
    fw.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "FW"
      vb.gui = false
      vb.memory = "1024"
      vb.cpus = 1
      vb.linked_clone = true
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/FW-Server"]
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "server" do |server|
    server.vm.hostname = "server"
    server.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.253", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
    server.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "ip route del default"
    server.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "ip route add default via 192.168.56.254"
    server.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "server"
      vb.gui = false
      vb.memory = "1024"
      vb.cpus = 2
      vb.linked_clone = true
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/FW-Server"]
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Provide internet access to VM in private network through another VM

Your second VM would have to have its own internet (USB NIC passthrough from host).

Then since VMs are normally NAT, you need to worked out how the first machine will connect to the second machine so that browsing on the first machine works.

Typically, Bridged Networking is better here but won't work given that machine B has its own Internet (USB Passtrhough).

It would be vastly easier if the machines could get Internet from the Host machine.

I connect Virtual Machines across machines and different subnets, so it should be possible. Once you get the machines connected, you should be able to share internet.

Connection is networking:  Network Discovery, File / Print sharing, Password protected sharing.

Comment: I think I've already done that. The first machine (FW) has a bridge network and in the second machine (server) I've defined the default gateway route as the IP of the first VM (FW).

Comment: Can you connect using Network Discovery concepts and the like connections?

Comment: If you mean that the VMs see each other, yes.

Comment: You could RDP / XRDP from one to the other to see internet on the other.

Comment: Typically a machine has Internet if the NIC is connected to the Internet. Can you see Internet traffic on either machine?

Comment: You might try an easier approach.  What you are trying to do is probably the most difficult way there is.  Make sure your edge security is top notch and then connect machines normally (all bridged, all with Internet).